# Reg Exp Capture everything before a certain word in VBA

Tags: regex, vba

Hi I want to capture everything before the word contact
Eg:

```
15 Lecky Road
Ballinderyy
Upper Lisburn
BT28 2QA
Contact: Anna Murphy
Telephone: 02892 610634
Fax: 02892 610635
```

This is my regexp:

```
(.|\n)*Contact$
```

Thanks

Comment: You may split the string with `Contact:` and grab the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do it with regex, this should do it for you:

```
^([\s\S]+)\s*Contact
```

It captures **everything**, including line feeds and stuff, up to the **last** occurrence of the word `Contact`. If there are multiple `Contact`'s and you just want to capture up to the first, change the RE to be non-greedy:

```
    ^([\s\S]+?)\s*Contact
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4sWqRW/3).

Comment: Thank you. I Needed to exclude contact as well, so I modified your formula a bit `^([\s\S]*)(?=Contact)`

Comment: OK. FYI - Then it's not really capture you wanted - it's a match ;) Match is everything the regex matches (doesn't include look-arounds), capture's what grabbed inside capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
answer=split(s,"Contact:")(0)
```

Far faster than regexp